# How to group a result set into a list from SQL statement?

Tags: java, jdbc

Suppose I want I have a SQL like `select * from game;`, but I want only one SQL to execute to group different games result into Java `List`.

Say we have game1, game2, game3 in the content of column 'game' in the resultset, so I need a `List` whose length is 3 and each element inside is a SQL ResultSet(if I can have a OR Mapping, that will be great) so that I can parse them later.

Comment: game1,2 and 3 are column right? if yes then you can just create a list within list and add the rows for each of the column to the corresponding list

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin No, game1, game2 are content

Answer (score 0):

SpringFramework contains a class called    JdbcTemplate which contains a method called query, this is will take a SQL statement with relevant parameters and return a    List with your results but it will require some work to set it up. I think you're looking for something a bit more 'out of the box' which just does it in a single line, but I don't think this is possible. There are other methods in the class which do the same thing but take different parameters based on what you have available in your code.

See [the JdbcTemplate api](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) for more details if you're interested.